# How can I pass parameters with i18next?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next

I want to translate my colors but idk how I do it.

```
const Item = memo(({ color, index, lastIndex, translateName, style, activeColor, onPress }: IColorItem) => {
  return (
      <Text>{translateName}</Text>
  )
  // @ts-ignore
}, isEq);

const Colors = ({ colors, style, activeColor, onPress }: IColors) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const renderItem: ListRenderItem<ColorsType> = ({ item, index }) => (
    <Item
      color={item}
      translateName={t('colors.color', { color: item })}
      index={index}
      style={style}
      activeColor={activeColor}
      lastIndex={colors.length - 1}
      onPress={onPress}
    />
  )
  return (
    <View style={s.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={colors as ColorsType[]}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        style={s.flatList}
        keyExtractor={(item, i) => i.toString()}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      />
    </View>
  )
}
```

transl.json

```
  "colors": {
     "color": "{{color, COLORS}}"
  },
```

Nothing works. How can I say "red" = ..., "blue" = ... ?

................................................................................................................................................

Comment: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can see in the i18n documentation the interpolation: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

```
{
"key": "{{what}} is {{how}}"
}


i18next.t('key', { what: 'i18next', how: 'great' });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way:

```
<Item
      color={item}
      translateName={t('colors.color', { color: 'blue' })}
      index={index}
      style={style}
      activeColor={activeColor}
      lastIndex={colors.length - 1}
      onPress={onPress}
    />
```

and in your json

```
  "colors": {
     "color": "my color is %{color}"
  },
```

the output should be: `my color is blue`

Comment: I want to translate the colors I have to say in want it translate in germany so I have to write the german colors somewhere